# Why do I have error with trained model from ubuntu to windows?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have trained the model on a super computer(ubuntu). After the training I used the model with Windows 10 and got this error:

```
SourceChangeWarning: source code of class 'torch.nn.modules.linear.Linear' has changed. you can retrieve the original source code by accessing the object's source attribute or set `torch.nn.Module.dump_patches = True` and use the patch tool to revert the changes.
  warnings.warn(msg, SourceChangeWarning)
```

**I can't load the model I trained.**

pytorch version in ubuntu: `1.1.0a0+9a7bcac`

pytorch version in windows: `0.4.1`

What is going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: How exactly is your "source change" detected? Might not be related, but usually when you copy files from GNU/Linux to Windows (and don't change their contents) some source control libraries can still detect a change because of file permissions: if such a library works with notion of Unix permissions, it will see all files on Windows attaining `exec` attribute, which might be seen as a change to files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT after comment discussion:
It seems like yor Windows version is outdated and there is thus a version conflict occurring. I would strongly suggest to update the version on Windows to post 1.0 release, which should fix the problem.

According to [this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/sourcechangewarning-source-code-of-class/12126), you can likely ignore the warning (not an error), as long as your model seems to still work as intended. The usual culprit for such changes is that you have inconsistent versions of PyTorch on your two systems, and therefore might encounter this warning.

Generally, the versions are supposed to be fully backward compatible, but of course there is no guarantee for this. It has nothing to do with the fact that you are on Linux and/or Windows, unless the source code detects changes in the line break character (which is the main difference from what I remember), although I think this is very unlikely to be the case.

Comment: But I can't load the model I trained.

Comment: Maybe like you said, pytorch version is different.

Comment: You never mentioned that this causes a complete failure of your model. I had similar issues that were non-critical, so I was assuming something along those lines, my bad. Feel free to edit the question with your respective information (i.e., that it failed to load completely, and at which stage), so people have a better idea of your problem :)

Comment: Thank you for your reminder,it's my first time ask question.I already edited more information.thx

Answer (score 0):

Thank dennlinger very much!
Is the problem of version.

After I update the pytorch version, it work!